# Invalid conversion from const char to char - Vowel Removal

Tags: c++, char

I'm trying to remove vowels from a text file and am having some trouble. I'm receiving a compiler error in line 6 saying

```
invalid conversion from const char to char
```

I'm pretty sure this has to do with the way I'm setting up the file stream in my code. I'm using fstream since it's used for reading and writing, but I didn't include any of the open modes because I thought I could write and read to/from the file without them (I'm pretty sure you have to use one, I'm just not sure which one.) Also, I'm not sure if the way I set up the equals operator is legal or not(will it read it as if s[i] is equal to a or e or i or o or u).

Code:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

void vowel_removal(string& s)
{
     for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i)
             if(s[i] == ('a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u')) s[i] = " ";
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter file name.\n";
    string filename;
    cin >> filename;
    fstream f(filename.c_str());

    string word;
    while(f>>word){
                   vowel_removal(word);
                   f << word;
                   }

    keep_window_open();
}
```

Comment: You should accept one of the answers given to your original question, and instead of editing this one, open a new question for your other problem.

Comment: Okay. Generally I've been under the impression that you should just edit your question if you have another one, but I"ll take your word for it.

Comment: I have rolled back this question to the original version, since the new versionis posted elsewhere ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191349/why-doesnt-this-change-the-txt-file ) and the answer does not match the new version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you mean invalid conversion from `const char *` to `char`

When you index a string you must assign a char not another string:

```
std::string s = "tie";
s[0] = 'l';
assert(s == "lie");
//s[0] = "l"; <--- not valid const char * to char
```

Also you must have both a right hand side and a left hand side for each comparison.  You can't apply one left hand side to multiple right hand sides in C++.

```
if(s[i] == 'a' || s[i] == 'e' || s[i] == 'i' || s[i] == 'o' || s[i] == 'u')
  s[i] = ' ';
```

Comment: Ah I see thank you. Would there be a shorter way to make the comparison?

Comment: The code compiles, but the text file doesn't change. I'm not sure why, but I'm guessing it has something to do with missing modes in the fstream argument.

Comment: You could do some other things like see if a char is in a string of different characters, but I think this is the most clear.  If you are going to do more than 1 comparison like that with all the vowels just make it into a function call something like bool isVowel(char c)

Comment: You should create a separate file for your output as your input.

Comment: As in create a separate file stream, or create a separate text file. Because I want to edit the actual file, not create a new one with the changes.

Comment: Note: This question conversation is continued at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191349/why-doesnt-this-change-the-txt-file .

Answer (score 0):

The reason the file doesn't change because you don't flush the stream